# How to group by mixed values and sort by date in a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am attempting to create a spreadsheet with a lot of data captured in it. The two requirements I have to meet are **1)** group jobs/parts with the same PROJECT #, and **2** sort by JOB START DATE. I thought PivotTables were the best way to do so, but I keep running into a brick wall. I'm either unable to group by Project # (most likely because they are a mixture of numbers and text, this cannot be changed), or I'm unable to sort by Job Start Date.

I've tried moving Project # and Job Start Date from Rows to Values, as well as changing the order they're displayed in (Job Start Date before Project # and vice versa).

[image: Screenshot of data in current PivotTable]
[image: Screenshot of Field List]

If grouped and sorted correctly, the records should show the grouped PROJECT # with the earliest start date first, then the next group with the next start date, etc.

An example would be:

```
>2074, 68506, BUC10626, 3/4/19
>>2074, 68568, AUC15393, 3/4/19
>>2074, 68570, AUC14509, 5/30/19

>2552, 69920, 99163786, 4/1/19
>>2552, 71066, H695359, 6/5/19

>1166, 71527, 5450926, 5/16/19

>2497, 71138, 2436-923, 6/11/19
>>2497, 73445, H646427, 7/24/19

>2704, 72682, AUC11771, 6/24/19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot tables build a hierarchy. If you have a cascade of Project > Job > Part > Date, then you can only sort by date within the container of the previous level, i.e. Part.

If you have more than one part in the hierarchy, then different dates will show up sorted inside that part, e.g.

```
ProjectA
   JobA
      Part A
         January    'these rows are 
         February   'sorted by
         March      'date
      Part B
         August
         September
      Part C
         March
         April
```

If you want the projects sorted by date, then you need to have the date column before the project column.

Comment: Thank you @teylyn! If I put the date before the project column, is there a way to still group the same projects together? Or is there a solution other than PivotTables that will achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: From your data sample it looks to me that your pivot table hierarchy should be Project > date > job > part. You need to understand the hierarchy levels.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!